# Scrollbar with tkinter labels

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I'm really struggling with Tkinter, I would like to create an agenda app and would need to have a scrollbar to display all the days with sufficient space between each day. I have been looking for different solutions and I came with this last one but it does not work, could someone offer me a solution?

Here is my code.

```
class App(Tk):
"""Un blocus a une date de début et une date de
fin, en paramètre il a également la liste de tous
les cours faisant partie du blocus."""
def __init__(self, liste_des_cours):
    self.c = Frame(fen)
    self.fen=fen
    fen.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    fen.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    start=Button(self.c, text="Créer planning",command=self.generer)
    start.grid(padx=100,pady=100)
    start.bind('<Enter>',self.generer)
    self.liste_des_cours=liste_des_cours
    self.generer()


def supp(self):
    for widget in fen.winfo_children():        
        widget.destroy()

def generer(self,event=None):
    """Génère l'interface graphique"""
    self.supp()
    self.canvas = Canvas(self.fen, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
    self.frame = Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
    self.vsb = Scrollbar(self.fen, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
    self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

    self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
    self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", 
                              tags="self.frame")

    self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
    self.populate()
    self.menu()
def populate(self):
    for a in range(7):
        Label(fen, text=weekdays[a],padx=60,pady=27).grid(row=1,column=a)
        for b in range(6,23):
            Label(fen, text=str(b)+"h",padx=60,pady=50).grid(row=b,column=a)


fen=Tk()
Appli=App(priority_object)
fen.mainloop()
```

Comment: What's your question? You've told us what you want but haven't asked for anything in particular.

Comment: Sorry Bryan, I've just edited, I just want my code to work.

Comment: If you're asking "how do I make a horizontal scrollbar work with a `Label`", the answer is "you can't". If you're asking "How can I scroll a long text item", you can use an `Entry` widget which supports a horizontal scrollbar.